# Transaction error while updating data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

Following error occurs while updating a particular data in my web application.I am using HibernateTransactionManager to manage all transactions in the application.

Error:-

> Pre-bound JDBC Connection found!
>   HibernateTransactionManager does not
>   support running within
>   DataSourceTransactionManager if told
>   to manage the DataSource itself. It is
>   recommended to use a single
>   HibernateTransactionManager for all
>   transactions on a single DataSource,
>   no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC
>   access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have more than one transaction manager in your application? The exception suggests that you do (a `HibernateTransactionManager` and a `DataSourceTransactionManager`), and that they're getting into a fight.

If you do have both, then you need to change it to using just a `HibernateTransactionManager`, and use that for all your transactions Hibernate *and* JDBC).

Comment: i am using  HibernateTransactionManager only... i am not using DataSourceTransactionManager.

Comment: As per the Spring Documentation, this exception is a bit misleading (Ref : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9496). Any mis-configuration, or 'a transaction based exception' which occurred previous to this exception will end up in this exception. Sometimes, even a restart, helps. Very beautifully explained in https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/spring-and-pre-bound-jdbc-connection-found/. I solved same exception in my app following these two links